# how to select rows based on condition sql

Tags: sql-server

I have table which contains the ids like -

```
id
o1
o2
o3
```

now another table contains price for these ids based on the country like

```
id    country     price
o1    IND         11
o1    US          10
o1    default     9
o2    default     2
o3    UK          4
o3    default     3
```

basically i have to write a stored procedure where i will pass the region as parameter. for example if region is UK then i want select rows as follows if there is match then select the row otherwise default row.

```
id       country        price
o1       default        9
o2       default        2
o3       UK             4
```

Can you please suggest a good and efficient way of writing in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CROSS APPLY` with `TOP`:

```
DECLARE @country VARCHAR(20) = 'UK'

SELECT  x.*
FROM tblId i
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM tblPrice p
    WHERE
        p.id = i.id
        AND (p.country = @country OR p.country = 'default')
    ORDER BY
        CASE 
            WHEN p.country = 'default' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
        END
)x
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses two `left join`s:

```
select ids.id, coalesce(p.country, d.country) as country,
       coalesce(p.price, d.price) as price
from ids left join
     prices p
     on ids.id = p.id and p.country = @country left join
     prices d
     on d.country = 'default';
```

I think a more interesting method uses `cross apply`:

```
select p.*
from ids cross apply
     (select top 1 p.*
      from prices p
      where p.id = ids.id and p.country in (@country, 'default')
      order by (case when p.country = @country then 1 else 2 end)
     ) p;
```